# Problems with drawing a random winning entry from a MongoDB database (with Mongoose & NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling to get the following code to work, using MongoDB, Mongoose and NodeJS. I have two schemas, one to save unique user profiles, the other to save their entries (such that they can enter multiple times). The entries all work (not shown here), it is just the selection of the winner that doesn't. It should randomly select one entry from the collection, find their unique profile and set the 'won' Boolean to true and delete all the entries in the collection. It currently does none of those things (but I've checked the routing all works fine and the const is triggered), so some assistance would be greatly appreciated. I've tried various methods, but found no clear guidance anywhere. Thanks.

**The controller**

```
const { Enter } = require('../models/user_entry');
const { UserProfile } = require("../models/User_Profile");

const drawWinner = async (req, res) => {
  const winner = Enter.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }]); 
  const users_profile = await UserProfile.findOne({ handle: winner.user });
  users_profile,{"$set":{"won":true}}; 
  await users_profile.save();
  Enter.deleteMany({  });
};

module.exports = {
  drawWinner
};
```

**The models:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Entry Schema
const EntrySchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const Enter = mongoose.model("entries", EntrySchema);

module.exports = { Enter };
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Profile Schema
const UserProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "user",
  },
  handle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  won: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});

const UserProfile = mongoose.model("profile", UserProfileSchema);

module.exports = { UserProfile };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `await` while aggregating the database

```
const winner = await Enter.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }]);
```

You might also want do `console.log(winner)` in order to check if are getting any data back from database.

**EDIT**

As per your comment you are getting `winner.user` value

The way you are using updating user is weird, try this instead

```
let updated_user = await UserProfile.findOneAndUpdate({ handle: winner.user }, { won: true },{ new: true });
```

You can delete these 3 lines

```
const users_profile = await UserProfile.findOne({ handle: winner.user });
users_profile,{"$set":{"won":true}}; 
await users_profile.save();
```

Also while `deleting` the entries use `await Enter.deleteMany({});`

You also need to send some response back `res.send()` otherwise server will hang.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I've added await and console.log(winner); console.log(winner.user);     and I still get error 500 from the server. I get the following in the server logs: 

```app[web.1]: [

app[web.1]:   {

app[web.1]:     _id: new ObjectId("620faf28dc6771be8cdf2e88"),

app[web.1]:     user: 'johndoe13',

app[web.1]:     __v: 0

app[web.1]:   }

app[web.1]: ]

app[web.1]: undefined```

I guess winner.user being undefined will prevent the rest from working. Do you know how to fix this, please?

Comment: check update!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! The winner.user was still undefined, so I did a bit of testing and found that the aggregate function was returning an array, not an object. I did the following to fix, then all worked: 
```const winner = await Enter.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }]);
    const winnerObject = await winner.shift();
    let updated_user = await UserProfile.findOneAndUpdate({ handle: winnerObject.user }, { won: true, $inc: {winnings: totals.thisWeek} },{ new: true });```
Thanks for your help.